# Is there a way to open all <a href> links on a page in new windows?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I have a bunch of `<a href=".html">` links and want to make them all open in new windows.

I know I can do a search and replace all to add `target="_blank"` to all my `<a href="...">` links.

However, is there a quick way, such as setting a CSS style, or adding some JavaScript code, to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: You can search and replace your project.

Comment: refactoring is always better than workarounds. You save yourself a lot of work in the long run. So just do a search and replace instead of introducing some javascript solution which additionally slows down your page.

Comment: I said I know I can do a search and replace -_-

Comment: No one asked a question, whether it is really needed. Why do you want all the links to open in new tabs / windows? As a result, your site will not be able to be displayed on some mobile devices (Kindle with browser with no tabs for example) and the users will complain (I hate it when the site opens even some links in new tab, not mentioning all, even internal ones). Links are for navigation, so why you want to avoid navigating user to the place where he wants to be?

Comment: @Tadeck I think with the BASE TARGET solution my page will work in these devices. it's a good solution.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you have a page consisting of only links, consider [`<base target="_blank">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/base). This opens every link in a new window (but also includes the targets of forms, unless overridden with `<form target="_self">`.

As others have shown, without modifying the HTML source, you can use Javascript to [iterate through all `<a>` tags and add the `target` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12235609/427545) or add an [event listener that sets the target attribute dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12235608/427545).

Answer (score 36):

If you have jQuery it's simple

```
$("a").attr("target", "_blank");
```

Or regular Javascript

```
var links = document.links;
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
     links[i].target = "_blank";
}
```

As per @Lekensteyn's suggestion, without Javascript (added for Completeness)

```
<base target="_blank">.
```

Comment: Instead of `getElementsByTagName("a")` you should use `document.links`. This has as advantaged that you only include links (i.e. `<a href>` elements) and not something like `<a name="foo">`.

Comment: This will not work for links which are added after the script is called.

Answer (score 14):

CSS: No.
JavaScript: Delegate a click event, which adds a `target="_blank"` attribute on click of a link.

```
document.body.addEventListener(function(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName.toUpperCase() === 'A' && e.target.href) {
        e.target.target = '_blank';
    }
}, true);
```

Note: If the `<a>` element contains other elements, you might want to traverse the tree to find out whether an anchor element is clicked:

```
document.body.addEventListener(function(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    do {
        if (target.nodeName.toUpperCase() === 'A' && target.href) {
            target.target = '_blank';
            break;
        }
    } while (target = target.parentElement);
}, true);
```

Or, if you're a jQuery-lover:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.target.target = '_blank';
});
```

Comment: can you explain how this JS works.

Answer (score 1):

yep, u can add attribute with JS to all links in HTML document named 'target' with value '_blank' ;)

You could also open replace href's of all links from url to javascript:openInWindow(url) using **this**, and writing function in JS that opens new window and set's it's location to **url** ;) Google will help you with both.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a html `base` element to the page using Javascript:

```
var e = document.createElement("base");
e.target = "_blank";
document.head.appendChild(e);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used pure vanilla JavaScript to create a script that makes all the links open in a new window.

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    var all_links = document.querySelectorAll("a");

    for (let index in all_links) {
        try {
            all_links[index].setAttribute("target", "_blank");
        }
        catch (error) {
            //console.log(error);
        }
    }
</script>
```